# Can I make a stair layout using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a stair-like layout using Bootstrap:

[image: stair-like layout]

To build this, I used below code

```
<div class="col-md-6 pull-left col-sm-12">...(img)...</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">....aaaaa.....</div>
```

I know this doesn't work, but what can I do to make that kind of layout using Bootstrap??

Comment: Please edit to add the image here instead of redirecting users.

Comment: In order to create that "layout` the image has to be **inside** the text element and floated. See the answer by Nikhil Eshvar below. HTML elements are **always** rectangular (although they can be made to *look* otherwise). Text only flows around floated elements.

Comment: always rectangular.. I hope this changes someday. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```css
img {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent fringilla vehicula arcu, vitae eleifend purus dictum sit amet. Etiam sollicitudin quis nunc id tempor. Aenean nunc mauris, varius ut turpis tempus, pretium egestas diam. In nunc quam, laoreet ut ex in, egestas finibus enim. Pellentesque accumsan vehicula semper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque dolor tortor, fermentum et sollicitudin in, pharetra eget odio. Aenean eget erat ante. Proin libero erat, tincidunt non posuere non, facilisis non enim. Praesent a dignissim ex. Phasellus viverra nec velit at tincidunt. Pellentesque lorem lectus, molestie vitae turpis a, dignissim aliquam dolor. Suspendisse consectetur, sapien non feugiat semper, ipsum lacus consectetur ligula, id laoreet ligula velit a lorem. Maecenas ac ante urna. Phasellus vitae mi nec tortor luctus viverra sed sit amet arcu.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent fringilla vehicula arcu, vitae eleifend purus dictum sit amet. Etiam sollicitudin quis nunc id tempor. Aenean nunc mauris, varius ut turpis tempus, pretium egestas diam. In nunc quam, laoreet ut ex in, egestas finibus enim. Pellentesque accumsan vehicula semper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque dolor tortor, fermentum et sollicitudin in, pharetra eget odio. Aenean eget erat ante. Proin libero erat, tincidunt non posuere non, facilisis non enim. Praesent a dignissim ex. Phasellus viverra nec velit at tincidunt. Pellentesque lorem lectus, molestie vitae turpis a, dignissim aliquam dolor. Suspendisse consectetur, sapien non feugiat semper, ipsum lacus consectetur ligula, id laoreet ligula velit a lorem. MadfsgsdgsdfgsdfgsdgsdfgPellentesque dolor tortor, fermentum et sollicitudin in, pharetra eget odio. Aenean eget erat ante. Proin libero erat, tincidunt non posuere non, facilisis non enim. Praesent a dignissim ex. Phasellus viverra nec velit at tincidunt. Pellentesque lorem lectus, molestie vitae turpis a, dignissim aliquam dolor. Suspendisse consectetur, sapien non feugiat semper, ipsum lacus consectetur ligula, id laoreet ligula velit a lorem. Madfsgsdgsdfgsdfgsdgsdfg
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes but using bootstrap grid system